# How create an object with keys which come from an array of keys without loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is an array which its items should be the keys of an object.
As an example:

```
['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

is my array. I need to have it like this object:

```
{
  'key1': '',
  'key2': '',
  'key3': ''
}
```

As it might be so items in array prefer not to use loops.
How can create object without loops?

Comment: By "without loops", do you mean "without `for` loops" or "without any kind of looping through an array"?

Comment: Any kind of loops. Not for , while, ... . It takes time to do it.

Comment: That's not possible. There's no built-in function in javascript like  python's `dict.fromkeys`. Your best bet would be `Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, '']))`, but that's a loop too.

Comment: ```obj = {
  [arr[0]]: "",
  [arr[1]]: "",
  [arr[2]]: "",
};``` That's it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an object from an array of keys and an array of values](/q/39127989/90527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also a loop, but at least it is a one-liner:

```js
const res=['key1', 'key2', 'key3'].reduce((a,c)=>(a[c]='',a),{});

console.log(res)
```

Comment: However it is a loop though, but worked better than others.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you're against using a loop. If you require the object to be created dynamically you won't really get away with not using a loop of some kind.

This solution technically doesn't directly use a loop ... but it's a silly solution and I don't recommend it.

```js
const keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];
const res = Object.fromEntries(
  JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(keys).replace(/"([^"]+)"/g,'["$1",""]')
  )
);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: isn't the ```replace``` method loop through the string as well?

Comment: @ikhvjs depends on your definition of a loop. Internally, yeah, there’s a loop. But in the code itself there is no actual loop.